# mysql query is not returning any row

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to get a row where total_votes are maximum, but this query is returning no row, infact it should return 1 row. Please help.

```
SELECT assembly, seat_code, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name), total_votes, party_id      
FROM polling JOIN seat USING (seat_id) JOIN candidate USING (candidate_id)
WHERE seat_id=1
HAVING total_votes = MAX(total_votes);
```

Comment: please show sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MAX` aggregate and remove the `HAVING` clause. See Below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
      assembly, 
      seat_code, 
      CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)name, 
      MAX(total_votes)total_votes, 
      party_id      
FROM polling JOIN seat USING (seat_id) JOIN candidate USING (candidate_id)
WHERE seat_id=1
) AS A
HAVING total_votes=(SELECT MAX(total_votes) FROM polling )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select assembly, seat_code, concat(first_name,' ',last_name), total_votes, party_id     
from (polling join seat using(seat_id) join candidate using(candidate_id))
where seat_id=1 and total_votes=(select max(total_votes) from <table name>);
```

Use this one

Comment: but why we can not use HAVING clause here?

Comment: A HAVING clause is like a WHERE clause, but applies only to groups as a whole, whereas the WHERE clause applies to individual rows. A query can contain both a WHERE clause and a HAVING clause. The WHERE clause is applied first to the individual rows in the tables . Only the rows that meet the conditions in the WHERE clause are grouped. The HAVING clause is then applied to the rows in the result set. Only the groups that meet the HAVING conditions appear in the query output